# How to add IE specific stylesheet in drupal 7 in drupal way

Tags: theming, hooks

I want to add this into my Drupal site in a Drupal way!

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="IE.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

I know it can be done easily by adding the above tag directly into html.tpl.php but I don't want hack the Drupal core and I want to follow a Drupal way for this.

What would be the best possible solution?

Comment: This is what you need [`template_preprocess_html()`][1]

Assuming, if you specifically want to make a condition for *Less than or Equal* to **IE8** then you should mention the below code:

    `function <YOUR-TEMPLATE>_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
      drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/fix-lte-ie8.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 8', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
    }`

Where, `fix-lte-ie8.css` is a **CSS file** created just under your **THEME** folder.
  [1]: https://api.drupal.org/template_preprocess_html

Answer (score 0):

You don't hack Drupal core if you add that to your **THEME's** html.tpl.php but anyway you can try implementing [hook_html_head_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7) in your theme's template.php

Comment: template_preprocess_html(), this was what I needed.